# Is playing the massively multiplayer online game Agar.io permissible?

Tags: halal-haram, image, game

[Agar.io](http://www.Agar.io) is online game. Can I play this game? Or I should play without any skins?

> Agar.io is a massively multiplayer action game created by Matheus Valadares. Players control a cell in a map representing a petri dish; the goal is to gain as much mass as possible by swallowing smaller cells without being swallowed by bigger ones. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agar.io))

Example usage:

[image]

Examples of skins:

[image: skins in agario]?

Comment: The more important question is what make you doubt it is halal? http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36200/do-we-need-to-check-whether-things-are-haram-when-they-probably-arent?

Comment: We seek effortful questions showing prior research.  Asking about permissibility without indicating a reason it's not the [default ruling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36838) is considered [off-topic](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/663).  Please [edit] the question accordingly.