# Is it permissible to read romance books?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, books, education

I love reading fiction books as entertainment. Unlike others, I tend to avoid watching TV, and instead read books which have numerous educational benefits. I read a variety of fiction novels, but I tend to sway towards romance books sometimes. I just wondered if it is fine to read such books. It's not as if I act upon these books at all in reality, I just like reading about them and following the plot storylines.

So, my question is: Is it permissible to read romance books?

Comment: Is there a reason why you may think it is haram? Somewhat relevant post: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36200/do-we-need-to-check-whether-things-are-haram-when-they-probably-arent

Comment: My answers are weird so I am adding it as comment. Everything has a Khair (goodness) and Shar (evilness) inside it. So before you do anything, first say the name of Allah on it, ask for Allah's forgiveness and now its Shar will not touch you and only Khair will be left. If you will do it all the time, then you will see, Snake will bite you but you will not be hurt by its poison. Allah has so much for the people who give thanks to Him. I tell you these things, so that I or someone else I don't know, become thankful servant of Allah. Ameen :)

Comment: One thing I would say is that as far as I can see romance novels depend on things which are haram, and revolve around non-believers.

Answer (score -1):

just remember that , if there is anything which gives you wrong direction or any passage or word which is not granted in islam or anything misguides you than you can't read this types of book.
moreover , no relation is granted in islam before marriage . so this types of story is not good for readers.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. This answer could be more helpful if your claims were supported by some evidences.